# Fill an UIBezierPath with a UIImage

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I got an UIBezierpath with a circle shape:

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:100];
```

But then i want to fill the circle with an UIImage (show only a portion of the image which is inside the circle)

Best Regards
Kristian

## Edit:

Thanks to Daniel and Dave for excellent answers :D saved me a lot of trouble ;D

The solutions:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddPath(ctx, path.CGPath);
CGContextClip(ctx);
```

and:

```
path.addClip;
```

Both works perfectly but i ended up using the last method (by Dave) because it required less code.

Comment: you probably want a masked image which should be done without bezier path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: as Dave DeLong points out, there's no need to use Core Graphics functions.  This should do the trick:

```
[path addClip];
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
```

Comment: +1, though you don't need to drop to CoreGraphics to do this.  You can use `-[UIImage draw....]` and `-[UIBezierPath addClip]` to do this.

Comment: Good call Dave -- I hadn't noticed the `addClip` method.  Updated the answer showing the UIKit implementation.